# What is Tesly and how to use it?

Tags: software-testing

I have been asked to research and study on this `Test Management tool` called [Tesly](http://www.tesly.com/)

I googled and I couldn't find anything related to that tool. Any document, any tutorial, nothing.

Can someone give me a link to download it, tutorials and get familiar with the tool?

Comment: What did you  e.g google for. With "tesly test management tool" looks like to give some hits.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be like asking for software recommendations at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have been asked to research and study on this Test Management tool called Tesly
>
> I googled and I couldn't find anything related to that tool.

Strange that. When I googled for `Tesly Test Management tool` it was right there on the first page of results.

I editted your (wildly off-topic) question for you, to provide a link to Telsy.

Had been a more successful googler, you might have read the front page of the tool, where it clearly says

> Due to a pending upgrade, Tesly is currently not open to new accounts.

So, that's your answer. Go back to management, tell them someone did the research for you and you won't be using Tesly - because you can't.